# Can't post a comment which contains -1

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, blocklist

I'm trying to post a simple comment; if the comment contains `-1`, then it errors out, suggesting I'm defending or replying to a downvote. This is to the OP, not a reply to my own Q or A.

[image]

Comment: Sure, but it borks on code :/ `['1'].indexOf() == -1`

Comment: @DanBron Well, to be fair, the `-1` appears inside a code mentioning snippet.

Comment: lol but not here..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've made this check a bit less greedy; your comment should go through now.

Comment: noice, I didnt think any changes would happen, have not encountered the message before, totally, understand preventing -1's etc.

Comment: -1 This works now. (wait, this actually goes through?, I think exactly this type of comment should be banned or am I missing something?)

Comment: None of this ever applied to meta, @MEEwasthemissingbracket

Comment: Discouraging pointless "+1 great answer" comments is a fine idea, but doing it with a regex is simply doomed to weed out perfectly good content. On top of that, there's no explanation given of exactly what triggers that red box: the text makes the bald assumption that the "+1" is there to herald an upvote, but doesn't mention that the "+1" is the culprit. The site has gone to great pains to clarify all sorts of rules, but this just seems harsh and vague, and it could be remedied easily with simple messaging improvements.

Comment: Much more detail [over on MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283874/remove-the-limitation-that-stops-comments-from-starting-with-1-or-1/283953#283953) @Pointy (if memory serves, SO is the only site where this actually applies). It's a fairly simple expression that looks for some sort of +/-1 pattern, tries to avoid false positives, and limits itself to comments under 120 characters (or thereabouts; been a bit since I've looked at it). The "rule", such as it is, isn't particularly concerned with the "+1" itself, it's intended to discourage comments that contain *little else*.

Comment: @Shog9 thank you for the clarification. In my particular case, though I certainly could have been more verbose, my tendencies of erudition suggested that a very simple statement ("`+1` means exactly the same thing as `1`") would be the clearest way of helping the questioner while I searched for a duplicate.

Comment: @Shog9 This [just came up on MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427246/comments-beginning-with-1-or-1-that-are-longer-than-120-characters-are-sup/427247#427247), but it appears that the character count only considers characters *after* the "+1" or "-1", so some comments that are longer than 120 characters are still blocked if the length is 120 or less after characters before them are excluded. Was this a deliberate decision, or unintentional? Also, as pointed out there, the limit appears to be only 100 for "+1" specifically?

Comment: Don't recall with certainty @sonic, but the expressions were written based on analysis of user behavior at the time so all else being equal I agree with Makyen. However, if *my* expressions are still in use then we're long overdue for fresh data collection and analysis there; I tweaked that stuff pretty regularly.

Comment: @Shog9 Ah, so that's why the threshold for "+1" was lowered by 20 characters.